# Nuxt.js get status 400 from express API on production mode

Tags: node.js, rest, express, nuxt.js

I develop an app with Nuxt and Express API on my local mashine. Here is all working fine.
Its a sigle Nuxt app with axios. The Express API is single too.

Now I put the API and Nuxt app on my server Ubuntu (Plesk). Now the API + Nuxt app is running, when I open Nuxt pages without asyncData or async fetch, it works also fine. But when I open (on reload) a page with the asyncData request I get an error:

Server error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

**This is working:**

- request from Postman to online API (status 200)
- go on page without asyncData and click on the link without reload (no SSR)

**This is not working:**

- SSR -> open direct URL to page with asyncData from API (In the server Logs give the API a status code 400)

Here is my short testing code:

**Express**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5555
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())

app.get('/public', (req, res) => {
  res.send('response')
})

app.listen(port)
```

**Nuxt.js**

```
asyncData ({ $axios }) {
  return $axios.$get(`https://api.domain.com/public`)
  .then((res) => {
    return { data: res }
  })
}
```

**the funny thing is that** when I make a request to (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos) the asyncData is working. Thats why I think it is a problem in my API

Comment: Do you have a response body as well? or just a 400 statuscode?

Comment: No there is not body in response

Comment: facing the same issue. Any solution?